# Windows Form Localization Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

When localizing a Windows Form, it creates a folder in the Debug folder for the language. In this case, I will use French (Canada) which is fr-CA. A folder named fr-CA gets created in the Debug folder that holds a FormName.resources.dll that it will use to look up information at run-time.

My issue is this. In my application I have a post build command to copy all of my executables and assemblies into one directory (Let's call it Main). Because of this, my assemblies are no longer in the same directory as the fr-CA folder and will use the default reference no matter what the Culture is.

In terms of the release process, what is the easiest or best practice for handling this? Do I need to create a fr-CA folder in the Main directory and put a post build event to copy the resource files there as well? Is there any way to handle this without having to release 1 resource file per language per form? This would end up being hundreds of extra files having to be released.

Comment: So is the issue that you are not copying the `fr-CA` folder, or that your main exe is not in the same folder as the fr-CA resource?

Comment: I don't want to change the fact that I am not in the same folder as the resource, so I'm wondering if there is some way to handle this without copying the fr-CA folder and all resources to the Main directory. The resource file itself is an embedded resource, but maybe there is some way to handle it similarly where it doesn't need to be in the same directory.

Comment: Your post-build event is broken, you'll need to fix it.  Sane way to go about it is to just avoid the copy.  Set the Output path setting on the Build tab correctly.

Comment: If the files need to be there then,  yes, I think changing the output path or doing an xcopy of everything in the TargetDirectory would be the best option.